# How to mock object that's created by a class builder?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermockito

In one of my running class currently i have:

```
void run() {
    Food food = new FoodBuilder(apple, peach, grape)
                    .build();
    food.eatFood();
```

My FoodBuilder class is like this:

```
public class FoodBuilder implements FoodInterface {
    private Food food = new Food();

    public FoodBuilder(Apple apple, Peach peach, Grape graph) {
        food.add(apple);
        food.add(peach);
        food.add(graph);
    }

    @Override
    public Food build() {
        return food;
    }
```

And my FoodInterface is:

```
public interface FoodInterface {
    Food build();
}
```

Now, I can't change the structure of this class, but I need to mock the `food` so I can bypass some permission issues in my service when calling `food.eatFood()`, basically I don't want to actually call `food.eatFood()`, instead I want to mock `food` so i can do `doNothing().when(food.eatFood())`.

I am using PowerMockito and my code is like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({FoodBuilder.class})
public class MyTest() {
    @Test
    public void mytest() {
        Food food = Mockito.mock(Food.class);
        FoodBuilder builder = Mockito.mock(FoodBuilder.class);
        when(builder.build()).thenReturn(food);

        doNothing().when(food).eatFood(); // This doesn't work! Because the food object is not a mock, instead it is a real object
    }
}
```

When I am running the test the `food` object is not a mock that I wanted, instead it is a real object that's being created so I can't tell `food.eatFood()` to `doNothing()`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your `Food` should be the thing implementing the interface.

Comment: @chrylis Legacy system, i can't change the soruce code.

Comment: If you want to test `run` method, this will be really hard to inject `FoodBuilder` mock there as you are creating new instance of `FooBuilder` locally with `new` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerMockito's `whenNew` functionality to intercept the constructor call.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    Food food = Mockito.mock(Food.class);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(food).eatFood();

    FoodBuilder builder = Mockito.mock(FoodBuilder.class); 
    Mockito.when(builder.build()).thenReturn(food);

    PowerMockito.whenNew(FoodBuilder.class)
                .withArguments(any(Apple.class),any(Peach.class),any(Grape.class))
                .thenReturn(builder);

    run();
}
```